# Need text to be displayed based on value of array

Tags: php, arrays, echo, shuffle

I have an assignment where a random prize must be awarded based on the number the user chooses.  Once that number is chosen it is stored and the array is shuffled and the prize is displayed.  I have that figured out but I also need text to be displayed based on what prize it ends up being and im getting stuck.

```
$award = array("bmw.jpg", "puppy.jpg", "grocery.jpg", "pen.jpg",          "gas.jpg", "iphone.jpg");
shuffle($award);
?>

<?php
echo '<img src="'. $award[$_GET["number"]].'" width="217" align="middle" >';
if($award['. $award[$_GET["number"]].'] == "bmw.jpg")
{
  echo '<p>Congrats you won the grand prize</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are running into? plz show the desired output and the current output..

Comment: remove quotes from `if($award['. $award[$_GET["number"]].']` --> `if($award[$_GET["number"]]  == "bmw.jpg"` just in case if this is not working.

Comment: How would I do that? currently I am not getting any text displayed if bmw is the prize that comes up

Comment: thank you @jitendrapurohit that worked perfectly!

Comment: Side note, it would be cleaner to store just the names, not the extensions in the array. Then you echo  the extension and you would also match `bmw` instead of `bmw.jpg`. Plus, you would only write `.jpg` once.

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks that is good to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your if statement like this:

```
<?php

if($award[$_GET["number"]] == "bmw.jpg")
{
   echo '<p>Congrats you won the grand prize</p>';
}
?>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, this is the solution. will vote when I am able too

Answer (score 0):

```
$award = array("bmw.jpg", "puppy.jpg", "grocery.jpg", "pen.jpg", "gas.jpg", "iphone.jpg");
shuffle($award);
$text = array("BMW", "Puppy", "Grocery", "Pen", "Gas", "Iphone");

?>

<?php
echo '<img src="'. $award[$_GET["number"]].'" width="217" align="middle" >';
if($award[$_GET["number"]] == "bmw.jpg")
{
  echo '<p>Congrats you have won '.$text[$_GET["number"]].' the grand prize</p>';
}
?>
```